# Set Build output directory in Eclipse - c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, linker

I have a program which consists of multiple projects in eclipse (working under ubuntu and the projects being in c++), these projects consist of a main executable file, and other shared objects files and static libs.

I want all these projects when built to output their files to one common binary folder, instead of their respective debug folders. This is to make linking easier with the main executable. If there are better solutions please also feel free to share.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have found that the **C/C++ Build** tab does not allow you to set the build location unless you are creating your own makefile.

You've likely found that the **Builder Settings** tab under **Project Properties>C/C++ Build** is all grayed out in a default C/C++ project. This is because CDT nominates the internal builder by default for new projects. To change this, you can go to **Project Properties>C/C++ Build>Tool Chain Editor** and change the **Current Builder** to **Gnu Make Builder**. Next, go to **Project Properties>C/C++ Build** and change the **Builder Type** to **External Builder**. You can now opt to create your own makefile for the project, if you like; though I'd recommend leaving CDT to build the makefile automatically for now.

I have the same project requirements of outputting to a /project_path/bin (though I still maintain separation between Debug and Release builds). To do this, I perform a copy operation on the output as a post-build step.

To do this, go to **Project Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings** and select the **Build Steps** tab. In the **Post-build steps** under **Command:**, enter:

```
cp ${BuildArtifactFilePrefix}${BuildArtifactFileName} "/path/to/bin/directory/";
```

Obviously replacing the "/path/to/bin/directory/" as required.

I personally prefer to maintain my project files in a *workspace/build* directory; copying binaries to a *workspace/bin* directory and libraries to a *workspace/lib* directory. At first I found this copy workaround to be an inconvenience, but have come to appreciate it because it isolates the interstitial build files from the final binary/library.

For binaries, I would use:

```
cp ${BuildArtifactFilePrefix}${BuildArtifactFileName} "${WorkspaceDirPath}/bin/";
```

For libraries, I would use:

```
cp ${BuildArtifactFilePrefix}${BuildArtifactFileName} "${WorkspaceDirPath}/lib/";
```

I include the variable "${BuildArtifactFilePrefix}" because CDT includes "lib" as a default prefix for static libraries, which I actually prefer.

You just need to ensure that the target directory exists before building; Eclipse/CDT will not create the directory for you.

Also, just remember that these copies will be left behind in the */bin* or */lib* directory on clean, but overwritten on any subsequent rebuild.

Comment: There is an option for a post-build step, so the easiest thing is to let it build where it does and if that works, use the post-build step to copy/move/link it. Is there a special macro for Debug or Release so I can use a common one for both configurations?

Comment: @CashCow the special macro is ${ConfigName} as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894878/3697870).

Comment: Unfortunately if you `mv` instead of `cp`, this workaround causes other problems. I wanted to move the entire "Debug" folder into an enclosing folder to avoid output folders with unstable names polluting my root directory. Alas, while the workaround can do this, I ran into a couple of strange "CDT Build" errors when building or debugging. It seems there's probably some baked in assumptions about the location of this folder. Mysterious build/debug errors are bad news when developing, so I think I'll roll back this workaround as "so close, but no cigar".

Answer (score 6):

Try `Project->Properties`

Under `C/C++ Build->Settings` you have a tab called `Build Artifact`.

Under there you have `Artifact name`. This defaults as `${ProjName}`.

Modify this to specify a relative directory path to where you actually want the final file to end up. So could be `../../lib/${ProjName}`

The intermediate files (.o and .d) will still build to the sub-directory (Debug or Release) but I guess it's better off if they are there anyway and it is only the finally built library for which you want to change the build path.

If you find it inconvenient typing the relative path like this, I use Environment to create environment variables with relative paths taking me back to a "root". One of this I have is `${LIBDIR}` and this is a relative path from where the project gets built. It is usually used for linking in other libraries, but can also be used as a target. Then you would set Artifact Name to `${LIBDIR}/${ProjName}` which works well if you use different directories for debug and release builds.

Comment: This has not any effect. Using Luna release 4.4.0. I can change name of executable, but path part is ignored.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks!
${workspace_loc:MyProject}/_runtime/${ProjName}

Answer (score 4):

Go to

#### Project Properties **->** C/C++ Build **->** Settings **->** (tab) GCC C++ Linker

The command line pattern is shown on the right side

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG}${OUTPUT_PREFIX} ${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

Put in front of `${OUTPUT}`

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG}${OUTPUT_PREFIX} ${ProjDirPath}/bin/${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

or

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG}${OUTPUT_PREFIX} MyMainProject/path/bin/ ${INPUTS}
```

From https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=207500&goto=665566&#msg_665566

Answer (score 2):

In my project the build path defaults to the Build Configuration name, so I could use a ${ConfigName} macro to retrieve the build path in a post-build step:

```
${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}/${ConfigName}/${BuildArtifactFileName}
```

Then you can copy target binaries to your common binary folder, or do something other in the build folder of that particular configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the project's properties, there is a tab C/C++ Build. This has an option for build location, where you can specify the build directory. It seems you could change this for your multiple projects so that they share the same build directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to be working on something that led me down a similar path - so I'll offer it up as an alternate solution/reminder to myself:

In Eclipse (at least in Luna) the generated makefiles are actually rather decent and convenient. I personally like to create several build configurations (Release and Debug variants with 32 and 64 bit architectures), and supplement them with debug and run (F5 and Execute, respectively) configurations.

To continue: I have been toying with packaging on Debian and found - during the act of said toying - that I needed to create and test an install target. Eclipse neither generates for you, nor provides an interface to - a configuration - for customizing or adding an install target; Other than a place where you can specify that another target exists.

So technically Eclipse does provide an interface; kinda. Hence, I stumbled across the *makefile.init*, *makefile.defs*, and *makefile.targets* files.

Process/Workflow:

- Create a file `makefile.targets` in the root directory of your eclipse project; In said file define an install target manually. *This - of course - allows you to specify every little detail as you'd like, but with the added benefit of all of the configuration provided by Eclipse already complete and available to you for use with defining the rules for the specified target.*
- After defining the new target in the `makefile.targets` file, *right click* on your project's name or main cpp file in Eclipse's `project explorer`, and then select `Make Targets`->`Build...`, and finally `Add` to instantiate a pop-up. *Alternatively, you could select 'create' in the last step instead of 'build' and it would provide the same pop-up required for the next part.* Add the *name* of your new target and - leaving everything else at their default values - click `ok`
- If you chose to add the new make target by *right-clicking* in *Project Explorer* and selecting *Make Target*->*Build...*, after *adding* the new make target you will be brought back to the first pop-up which resulted from selecting *Build...*. Otherwise, find your way to the `Make Targets`->`Build..` pop-up now. Select the desired target and then click on `Build`.

Looking through Eclipse's auto-generated makefiles was an excellent way to learn the makefile syntax and overall structure, and get into some advanced usage of includes and conditionals.

Here are some portions of an example makefile, which - at least I hope - will demonstrate manually setting the output directory of a build:

```
prefix = /usr/local
bindir = $(prefix)/bin
sharedir = $(prefix)/share
mandir = $(sharedir)/man
man1dir = $(mandir)/man1

...
# Typical all target
all: <binaryname>

#Typical clean target
clean:
rm -f <binaryname> <objectname>.o

# Target invokes all, then installs to specified locations
install: all
install <binaryname> $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
install -m 0644 <objectname>.1 $(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)
```