# Change output directory of an Eclipse CDT project

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I cannot find the possibility to change the output of the built files. The only I've found deactivates the *whole* generated makefile process, which I don't want to.

Comment: As detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882231/set-build-output-directory-in-eclipse-c#comment137460409_9286467) I don't think this is possible without breaking other CDT functions, sadly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Right-click on your project and choose Properties.
2. Go under C/C++ Build, under Settings.
3. Click on the Build Artifact tab.
4. Under "Output prefix", enter the directory that you want to contain your built file (including a trailing slash).

It looks like you'll also need to modify your Run / Debug Settings with the updated path.

(However, writing your own makefile really isn't hard, especially if you use Eclipse's generated makefiles as a starting point, and it can give you a lot more flexibility.)

Comment: @josh-kelley: it works nearly perfect, the file is built. What the directories Debug and Release are still created containing the makefile and the object file. I would like to generate all of them in my specified directory.

Comment: @platzhirsch: From browsing project options, I don't see a way to relocate intermediate files.  If you rename your Debug and Release build configurations, then that would rename the directories used to store the intermediate files.  You could also try using symlinks (if your OS supports them) to point from Debug and Release to the directories you want to use.

Comment: @josh-kelley: sadly renaming works only for the base folder. I think I have to go for customized make file. I guess this would mean deactivating the makefile generation and modify it?

Comment: @platzhirsch: I'd recommend trying symlinks.  (Try something like `cd ~/workspace/my-project; rm -r Debug; ln -s /debug/directory/i/want/to/use Debug`).  Otherwise, yes, you can deactivate the makefile generation then modify the makefiles.