# Eclipse - how to change the build directory?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

[image]

If makefiles are generated automatically, the output directory cannot be changed. It is poisoning my oxygen documentation. I would like to build to a different directory and have automatic makefiles generation enabled. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882231/set-build-output-directory-in-eclipse-c

Comment: Probably unrelated but what does _hot wo_ mean in the title of your question?